# If “shipping to different address” is checked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Can anyone please tell me how to detect if “shipping to different address” is checked?
I wish to unset custom billing fields when the client select the checkbox “shipping to different address”...

I've tried this but it didn't worked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

parse_str(html_entity_decode($instance), $postData);
if ( $postData['ship_to_different_address']  ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_pp']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_cc']);
}
return $fields;
}
```